# The last element of recursive function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, recursion

I wrote a recursive function to find the biggest number path in the matrix. Only move for down and right allowed. (if you can move to down you have to go)

My question is not about the algorithm, I really confiused why I get undefined the end of the recursion. I can see the last element and it is not undefined. Thanks for any help! :)

```
function solution(A = []) {
      let c = A[0].length; // m
      let r = A.length; // n

      let pathLength = c + r - 1;

      console.log(A[0][0]);

      if (pathLength === 1) return A;

      if (0 < c && A[0][0 + 1] > A[0 + 1][0]) {
        //go right
        A.forEach(element => {
          element.shift();
        });
        solution(A, A[0][0]);
      } else if (0 < r - 1) {
        // go down
        A.shift();
        solution(A, A[0][0]);
      }
    }

    const testcase = [
      [9, 9, 7],
      [9, 7, 2],
      [6, 9, 5],
      [9, 1, 2]
    ];

    output:
    9
    9
    7
    9
    5
    2
    undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `length` needs -1 on the end of it, as arrays are indexed from 0, but length counts from 1.